# Close frame "Tabs" from Salesfroce with Ruby On Capybara

Tags: ruby, capybara

I'm trying to create a ruby automation on Salesforce, and there when I click in the result of the search, appears for me a "TAB" like below, and I need to close this , but I am not successful, below are my code, some one can help me?

[image]

```rb
within_frame(xpath: "/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[4]/em") do
  Close
  #dispose()
end
```

Comment: Without an example of the HTML you're trying to click on this is impossible to answer. The code you have shown is never going to work since `within_frame` is for scoping into an `<iframe>` element , and the method doesn't take an `xpath` option like you're passing (it does take a selector type `within_frame(:xpath, '...')`) and would need to find an `ifram` element not an `em`

Comment: Nice, thanks for this explanation calas, and sorry for my examplo, I tried to use something from my environment.